# how to import a class from dll?

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

**mydll.dll**

```
namespace mydll
{
    public class MyClass {
        public static int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x +y;
        }
    }
}
```

In another project how can I import MyClass or just Add function?

I want to add with **DllImport**,

> [DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet =
>   CharSet.Auto) ] public static extern
>   .......

how can I do that?

Comment: Are you using C# on both sides of the application (class definition and class consumer)? If you are, there might be [a better way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Reflection to load assembly at runtime.

Here a piece of code you can use :

```
Assembly myAssembly ;
myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("myDll.dll");

object o;
Type myType =  myAssembly.GetType("<assembly>.<class>");
o = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257) you can find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

`DllImport` is used to call unmanaged code. The `MyClass` class you have shown is managed code and in order to call it in another assembly you simply [add reference to the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t.aspx) containing it and invoke the method. For example:

```
using System;
using mydll;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int result = MyClass.Add(1, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: No I want to add dll while program running, not with add reference option, so how can I create a unmanaged dll?

Comment: @ocanal, you could load an assembly at runtime using Reflection and the [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) method. Once the assembly is loaded you could list all the types inside and invoke methods on them.

Answer (score 0):

If both sides are .NET, you still need some common interface (or use dynamic). If you have that in place, you can use Reflection or the ComponentModel.